# Is it possible to persist type assertion of a variable, or have a "type assertion block"?

Tags: typescript

Consider something like this:

```
type BodyTypeA = {
    width: number;
    height: number;
    label: string;
    id: string;
    importantNumber: number;
    // Many other BodyTypeA specific fields
}

type BodyTypeB = {
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

type BodyTypeC = {
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

class PhysicsObject {
    body: BodyTypeA | BodyTypeB | BodyTypeC

    createFromSprite(...) {
        this.body = // This is what I use and it will create a BodyTypeA body
    }

    createFromJson() {
        this.body = // This will set body to BodyTypeB body
    }

    createFromWhatever() {
        this.body = // This will set body to BodyTypeC body
    }
}
```

I wrote that on a notepad, so there could be some issues.

My problem is that I have a situation where I have objects which are instances of `PhysicsObject`. This `PhysicsObject` class and its typings are owned by a third-party library and I cannot / don't want to edit them. Every `PhysicsObject` has a `body`-field with three possible `BodyTypes` - I don't know why, but that's just how it is.

I am basically only creating `bodies` for `PhysicsObjects` with the `createFromSprite`-method, which creates a `BodyTypeA` body for the `PhysicsObject`.

The issue here is that when I create a body and then want to set `id`, `label` and many other fields for the body, I have to do it by constantly asserting that the `physicsObject.body` is of type `BodyTypeA`:

```
let physicsObject = new PhysicsObject();
physicsObject.createFromSprite(...);

(physicsObject.body as BodyTypeA).label = "abc";
(physicsObject.body as BodyTypeA).id = 124;
let saveImportantNumber = (physicsObject.body as BodyTypeA).importantNumber;
...
```

So I am wondering if I could somehow persist the type assertion here, without touching any of the third-party library code or types?

I am looking for something like this:

```
let physicsObject = new PhysicsObject();
physicsObject.createFromSprite(...);

// Assertion block?
(physicsObject.body as BodyTypeA) {
    // No need to spam type assertion
    physicsObject.body.label = "abc";
    physicsObject.body.id = 124;
    let saveImportantNumber = physicsObject.body.importantNumber;
    ...
}

// Just assert it and persist somehow?
physicsObject.body as BodyTypeA;

// No need to spam type assertion
physicsObject.body.label = "abc";
physicsObject.body.id = 124;
let saveImportantNumber = physicsObject.body.importantNumber;
...
```

Or is there some other way to do something like this that I'm not aware of?

For whatever reason when creating the `body` with `createFromSprite`, the type of the `body` doesn't like "collapse" to `BodyTypeA`. I am not sure if this is something that TypeScript should do, but if so, it doesn't happen here. I believe that `createFromSprite` doesn't exactly create a `BodyTypeA` body, but instead wants to keep it general enough. However, fields like `id` and `label` definitely don't exist on `PhysicsObject.body` created with other methods than `CreateFromSprite`.

Comment: After calling `createFromSprite` you're _still_ accessing `physicsObject` via the `PhysicsObject` interface, there's nothing to "collapse". It seems like the thing you're using is very badly structured, maybe putting a facade around it with a more comprehensible interface would be worthwhile? E.g. I would have `body` based on a generic type, then e.g. `createFromSprite` is a _static_ method returning `PhysicsObject<BodyTypeA>`, which you can get close to with a function returning `PhysicsObject & { body: BodyTypeA }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can persist the type assertion of a *variable*, but not of an object property (since that might get mutated in the meantime).

```
const body = physicsObject.body as BodyTypeA;
body.label = "abc";
body.id = 124;
let saveImportantNumber = body.importantNumber;
```

Comment: Ahh of course! Out of interest, got a second to comment on if it would be an insane idea to have TS support a sort of "type assertion block" as shown in my question?

Comment: As mentioned, the object might get mutated in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to just assign the body to its own variable and type that like this:

```
const body = physicsObject.body as BodyTypeA;

body.label = "abc";
body.id = 124;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=15&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9gExAFXBAglAvFA3gWACgoSoB3ASwWAAsAuKAOwFcBbAIwgCcBuI0qDQgUA5jWAMWHbn2KkANgENO8hgGdgXCoxGyBVSW069+pCqzBwuwRY2AA5I90PSTckgHoPUALK2QUHC03LCIKGiYapAAxhQAZhTRUAkQ8ghqRAC+RESgkKFIqJAw2HimJJTU9ExObgJCouIuxrLZhLloBeGQAMKlBO7kVLTNMuWCwmISNa6tOYTawNxxitHQAAo0IGqJagDy7ABWENHAZe7sYQD8DPCFEVAAPl1FECXPd90QPXPthPIQM5gLY7aL7I4naabba7A7HU79KCXJAMXCZKCKNQvB4fMKvd7Y3qZWREaJwRgaJFhUrAmFguGQgB0yICmMJGBJhBZjKUKlKACJlNF+bJuVRSgBGABMABYeEA)

---

Another way would be to use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), this however does require your `createFromSprite` to set the `id`, but it is a safer way to do things:

```
if (isBodyTypeA(physicsObject.body)) {
    physicsObject.body.label = "abc";
    physicsObject.body.id = 124;
}

function isBodyTypeA(body: BodyTypeA | BodyTypeB | BodyTypeC): body is BodyTypeA {
    return body.hasOwnProperty('id');
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Thank you! I will mark Quentin's answer as accepted though, seems like he was a bit faster than you :)

Comment: @Swiffy no problem :) I've added another solution with proper type predicates